# How to create method that hits an API based on a one sec interval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm creating a lib that I will have delayed_job run as a background service on heroku.

The point of the lib method will be to hit a API to process a lot of data. The API I'm hitting has a limit of 600 Graph API requests per 600 seconds.

That being said, I'd like to know if it would be possible to make sure my delayed job doesn't go over this.

Something like:

```
requests_made = 0
@items.each do |x|

    if request_made >= 600
        pause for 1 second??????? Is this possible?
    end

    ### HIT THE API
    requests_made = requests_made + 1
end
```

Is something like this possible? Is pausing possible? Heroku's delayed jobs will run a job for up to 4 hours so I don't see timing out being a problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep(1)` is probably the most explicit and simplest method. Will using this be a problem?

**Added as a response to the comment**

To measure the time spent on calling an API, do

```
start_time = Time.now
call_the_API
spent_time = Time.now - start_time
```

Then you can do some conditionals on `spent_time`.

Comment: I don't think so? I've never used sleep before

Comment: Any ways to time it, so determine how long it takes to run the API call and then subtract that from 1... And if the value is + , then sleep?

Comment: @AnApprentice I added how to measure the time spent on API.

Comment: @AnApprentice, once you have `spent_time`, see if it's `> 1`. If it is then immediately continue instead of sleeping. Also, `sleep()` takes fractional values, so if `spent_time < 1` you can `sleep(1.0 - spent_time)` to have the code pause less than a second, helping to keep you on track. If it's not that important you can simply `sleep(1)` always and you'll do a little less than 600.